# PC cannot identify the ST-LINK

Tags: stm32, usb-drive, stm32f4discovery

The development board is STM32F4DISCOVERY, which includes an ST-LINK embedded debug tool. Recently, my computer cannot identify the ST-LINK on it. The Device Manager shows that '**Unknown USB Device（Device Descniptor Request Failed)**' with a yellow '**!**'.Besides, the LD1(LED) on the board change between Red and Green every 5s. Below is the SCH of the ST-LINK.

ps: I've already re-install the device driver, changed the micro-USB cable and even tried on another computer. Still not work.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar behavior when I shorted-circuit on 5V (of course accidentally). Please check voltage on D1, on both sides must be 5V.

Also, if the voltage is OK, I would recommend testing board on another PC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, D1 brokedown at early times. So I removed it and connected U5V, 5V with silver ink. It worked normally at that time.